# whats the order of a distributional derivate?

Tags: terminology, distribution-theory

I have to calculate the derivatives of order $\le 2$ of for example $f(x) = |x|$, is it the same as the second derivate, what does this "of order $\le 2$" mean? calculating distributionell derivatives is easy, for my example it would be
$$
 \langle f', \phi \rangle = - \int_{-\infty}^0 -1 \phi' \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{\infty} 1 \phi' \mathrm{d}x = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \phi' \mathrm{d}x = -2\phi(0)
$$
is guess.

Comment: for $f(x)=[x]$   from (-infinity,0)  $f(x)=-x$  and $f'(x)=-1$,from [0,infnity)  $f(x)=x$ so $f'(x)=1$

Comment: By the way, your computation of the first distributional derivative is incorrect. 

$$ \langle f',\phi\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^0 x\phi' \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^\infty x\phi' \mathrm{d}x $$

Perhaps you intended to compute the second distributional derivative of $f$ in your question statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A distributional derivative of order 1 is the first derivative.

A distributional derivative of order 2 is the second derivative.

A distributional derivative of order 3 is the third ...

We write "of order $N$" instead of the $N$th derivative because, among other reasons, (1) that in the multivariable context there isn't just *the* second derivative. When your domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$ there are three independent second derivatives; (2) it makes possible for expression like "of order $\leq N$" which is a short hand for "the collection of first, second, ... , all the way up to $N$th derivatives".